# How to convey the sense of "scare the bejesus out of me"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques, religion

> Scare the bejesus out of sb: to frighten, annoy, bore, etc. someone very much [[Cambridge]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scare-the-bejesus-out-of-sb).
>
> Scare the bejesus out of sb: To shock or frighten one very suddenly or severely. ("Bejesus," a mild euphemistic oath, is here used as an intensifying noun.) [[Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scared+the+bejesus+out+of) Free Dictionary]

E.g.

> The sound of the fire alarm scared the bejesus out of us this morning.

For more information of bejesus (derived by "by Jesus") see here [[ESE]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86868/meaning-of-bejesus-in-the-idiomatic-expression-the-bejesus-out-of)

What are some common ways to express a similar idea in French?

Comment: « — L’alarme incendie nous a fait paniquer ce matin. »

Comment: I think this is a metaphor for something so terrifying that it would unseat any existing or incumbent religious beliefs you might have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a slang, *banlieues* speech register version :

> *Ce matin, l'alarme incendie, elle nous a fait flipper notre race !*

Beware that the register of *flipper sa race* is probably quite the opposite of the English expression "scare the bejesus of someone"...

A still colloquial but less distinctive alternative can be:

> *Elle nous a fait flipper grave !*

Comment: Ou peut-être juste "fait flipper" qui est moins connoté "banlieues" et très répandu parmi m'a génération (30-40 ans)

Comment: @JacquesGaudin "Flipper" tout seul n'a pas vraiment le même sens.

Comment: "Flipper" = "avoir peur" non ? Ajouter "race" donne effectivement une connotation très "banlieue", mais sans ca l'expression ne perd pas son sens selon moi.

Comment: @LaurentS.*Flipper* évoque plus pour moi une angoisse sourde, intériorisée alors que *scare the bejesus out of me* me semble être une sensation brusque et violente. C'est pour ça que je propose *flipper sa race* où *sa race* tient lieu d'intensificateur. Une variante moins « connotée banlieues » peut être *elle nous a fait flipper grave*.

Answer (score 8):

« Il y a l'alarme-incendie qui s'est déclenchée ce matin, on a failli faire une crise cardiaque tellement on a eu peur ! »

Answer (score 3):

Quebec slang with (mild) expletive "crisse" French would be:

> L'alarme d'incendie ce matin nous a fait peur en [crisse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/crisse)!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers:

"L'alarme incendie nous a fait la peur de notre vie!"

Answer (score 3):

You can also use “*foutre la trouille*”, which usually conveys a notion of suddenty:

> L'alarme incendie nous a foutu la trouille [de notre vie] !

Although “*foutre*” is quite informal here, it would not be considered as vulgar/slang in this context, unlike in “*va te faire foutre !*” (“*fuck off!*”).

Adding “*de notre vie*” (“*of our life*”) enforces the feeling of severity, although it is usually not used in the litteral sense.